# Virtual hosts not working despite the host pointing to local IP and being configured right

Tags: wamp, wampserver

The major problem is that they had worked previously with this exact configuration and I have yet a clue as to what changed.

The hosts file is configured as follows

```
127.0.0.1               localhost
::1  localhost
127.0.0.1               localhost

127.0.0.1               geckoparc.loc
127.0.0.1               cenaclu.loc
127.0.0.1               quagga.loc
127.0.0.1               woo.loc
```

The vhosts as follows

```
<Directory D:/Dropbox/wamp/www>
    Order Deny,Allow   
    Allow from all 
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/GeckoParc/"
    ServerName geckoparc.loc
    ServerAlias geckoparc.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/cenaclu-2015/"
    ServerName cenaclu.loc
    ServerAlias cenaclu.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/quagga/public/"
    ServerName quagga.loc
    ServerAlias quagga.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/\woocommerce/"
    ServerName woo.loc
    ServerAlias woo.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

Originally this worked from a remote folder, added to Dropbox to sync between work stations. I have tried using the local vhosts from conf/extra in the wamp directory but to no avail.

The error that I get while in browser:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://woo.loc/

Unable to determine IP address from host name woo.loc

The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
This means that the system was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.
```

But pinging from command line gives a response from local

```
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes =32 time <1ms TTL=128
```

Any ideas what I could try? Keep in mind this is WAMP, so windows. Thank you!

I will update this question after testing this from home, to make sure it isn't related to the workstation somehow.

**AS PROMISED, AN EDIT**

I checked the same configuration on my home PC (the file system is set up the same way) and it works. Will try to reinstall WAMP at work and see if that fixes anything.

**EDIT NO 2**

After re-installing wamp stack on my work PC the issue persists. I have removed and created the vhosts again in it's extra/conf with the suggestions made by RiggsFolly bellow, still no go. I am assuming it has something, somehow, to do with my machine. I will share it here if I figure out what.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: WAMP Version 2.5 with Apache Version 2.4.9, PHP Version 5.5.12  and MySQL Version 5.6.17.

Answer (score 0):

See this typo 
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/\woocommerce/"

remove the backslash to make it

```
DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/woocommerce/"
```

Also remove the trailing slash like so, (applies to all virtual hosts)

```
DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/woocommerce"
```

It is also better to include the access rights within each individual Virtual Host definition like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/\woocommerce/"
    ServerName woo.loc
    ServerAlias www.woo.loc
    <Directory D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/woocommerce>
       Order Deny,Allow   
       Allow from all 
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also if you are using a WAMPServer that comes with Apache2.4 you could change the access syntax to that used by Apache2.4 and not use the old Apache2.2 syntax like so :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/\woocommerce/"
    ServerName woo.loc
    ServerAlias www.woo.loc
    <Directory D:/Dropbox/wamp/www/woocommerce>
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I will make sure to include the access rights individually, thank you. The problems iitself sn't coming from vhosts, the same file is loaded on my home PC and works fine (I keep it synced over Dropbox).